# Migrated Visual Studio extension package does not load when building from commandline

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins, vsix

Some years ago we made a Visual Studio Add-in, which uses the build events as trigger for the action. The Add-in was working in the `IDE` and the `Command Line` mode. To load the Add-in for command-line builds, you had to set the  `<CommandLineSafe>1</CommandLineSafe>` option.

The migrated extension works in the `IDE` mode, but the extension is not loaded during command-line builds.
How is the configuration to load the extension for command-line builds?

Answer (score 0):

Information about loading Visual Studio extension packages can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.provideautoloadattribute.aspx

You can mark your package class with the `ProvideAutoLoadAttribute` in combination with an UI context, for instance:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.EmptySolution)]
public class MyCustomPackage : VSPackage
{
    ...
}
```

It´s possible to have more than one attribute specified. Available UI contexts are defined by the [UIContextGuids](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.uicontextguids_members(v=vs.90).aspx) type.

In one of my extension I use a combination of the following UI contexts to assure that my package always loads irrespective whether there´s a solution loaded, or not: `EmptySolution`, `NoSolution`, `SolutionExists`.

Comment: I had already these attributes:
`[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.EmptySolution)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.NoSolution)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionExists)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionBuilding)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionHasMultipleProjects)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids.SolutionHasSingleProject)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.SolutionExistsAndNotBuildingAndNotDebugging)]`
in my code.

Comment: If I call 
`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /rebuild "Debug|Any CPU" "Solution.sln"`
the package is not loaded.

Comment: Have you checked the activity log? Maybe there´s a another problem which prevents the extension from loading...

Comment: From the log:
`<entry>
    <record>2134</record>
    <time>2015/08/26 06:18:49.150</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Importing pkgdef file</description>
    <path>C:\USERS\BFJS\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\BFJS\VSIXPROJECT2\1.0.1\VSIXProject2.pkgdef</path>
  </entry>`

Comment: And:
`<entry>
    <record>2561</record>
    <time>2015/08/26 06:18:51.461</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Successfully loaded extension...</description>
    <path>C:\USERS\BFJS\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\BFJS\VSIXPROJECT2\1.0.1\</path>
  </entry>`

Comment: And:
`<entry>
    <record>2565</record>
    <time>2015/08/26 06:18:51.462</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Extension Manager</source>
    <description>Extension is enabled...</description>
    <path>C:\USERS\BFJS\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\14.0EXP\EXTENSIONS\BFJS\VSIXPROJECT2\1.0.1\</path>
  </entry>`